# Divisibility by $2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that a number is divisible by $2^n$ if and only if its last $n$ digits are.

This proof involves modulo base $10$ but I can't seem to quite figure it out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *"This proof"* - **which** proof is that? Are you looking at a book or other resource?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Any number minus the last n digits end in n zeroes. Thus the difference is divisible by $10^n$.

Now use the fact that $2^n |10^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Any number in the base $10,$

can be represented as $\sum_{0\le n\le r}a_n10^n\equiv \sum_{0\le n\le m-1}a_n 10^n\pmod{10^m} \equiv \sum_{0\le n\le m-1}a_n 10^n\pmod{2^m}$

Answer (score -1):

I will give you some solid examples and explain why it works.

A positive integer is divisible by $2$, if the last digit is $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$, $8$. It means you may have big numbers, e.g., $1234567890$, and say "it's an even number because the last digit is zero." In other words, you don't need to worry about the left digits before the last one to check its divisibility by 2.

Now, you know $0$, $4$ and $8$ are divisbile by $4$. And positive integers greater than $10$, are divisible by $4$, if the last $2$ digits combined are divisible by $4$. For example, $1364$ is divisible by $4$, because you may separate it into a sum $1300+64$, where $1300=13\times100$ is a multiple of $100$, and $100$ is divisible by $4$. Also the number composed by the last $2$ digits $64$ is also divisible by $4$. As you have a sum where the two factors $\left(1300\;\text{and}\; 64\right)$ are divisible by $4$, then the result $\left(1364\right)$ is also divisible by $4$.

This same principle aplies to the divisibility by $8$, where you separate the number into a sum of a multiple of $1000$ (which is divisible by $8$) and a $3$-digits factor.

Same to divisibility by $16$, where you separate the number into a sum of a multiple of $10000$ and a $4$-digits factor.

So, the general principle is if you want to check the divisibility by $2^{n}$, then you may separate an integer into a sum of two factors: a multiple of $10^{n}$ (which is divisible by $2^{n}$) and directly check the divisibility of the other factor smaller than $10^{n}$ by $2^{n}$.